# In lubuntu autostart dual screen works properly only after every shutdown and boot, but it does not show properly after reboot

Tags: lubuntu, screen, shutdown, autostart

I have lubuntu 13.10 in a P4 laptop with external screen.
 I have set Arandr on startup to open dual screen in extend mode.
When I shutdown computer and I boot again, the dual screen works fine.
But when I reboot my computer without shutdown first,
the dual screen is not working properly and I have to set it manually using Arandr
Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

I installed manually `disper-indicator`. I also created a `disper-indicator.desktop` file in `/etc/xdg/autostart` and I run command `disper-indicator` on startup.

Then, after reboot I setup dual screens using `disper-indicator`.

Answer (score 0):

ok problem solved.
I used in autostart another application which is called disper. 
 I did not use Arandr in autostart but disper.
there is a command

disper -d CRT-0,DFP-0 -r auto -e -t right

where CRT-0 is replaced with the name of your left monitor.
DFP-0 is replaced with the name of your right monitor.

I set this command in autostart so it starts in every reboot.
it is like Arandr but it works better for me.
Then I ticked no different background image in second screen.
so I choosed one image that its width is the sum of widths of both screens
and I set that image as background.
And now it works ok.